# Accuracy in multiplication; precision in addition

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

Why is it that while multiplying approximate numbers we are concerned with significant figures (accuracy) and while adding we are concerned with decimal places (precision)? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Edit : When multiplying approx numbers of different significant figures, the final result is given correct to as many significant figures as the least accurate number given.
While adding approx numbers of different precisions, the final result is given so that it is as precise as the least precise of the given numbers. 
Why is it so?

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit by providing context?

Comment: Editing now....

Comment: could you show us some concrete examples

Comment: 245.72+258.8+17.5+0.0087+0.00031+41.5 ≈ 563.5 (same precision as the least precise 17.5 or 41.5 or 258.8)

Comment: 171.72×51.027×0.0085 ≈ 74 (as accurate as the least accurate 0.0085)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem should become clear by proper understanding of what significant figures mean. Significant figures measure *relative error*. For example, say the exact number $a=12.341111...$, and when rounding $a$ to four significant figures, we obtain
$$\tilde a =12.34$$
Say now we only know $\tilde a$. It gives us an approximate value to the real value $a$, and more importantly, how *approximate* this value is. That is to say, we're assured that
$$a=\tilde a \left( 1+ \delta \right)$$
where
$$ | \delta | < 10^{-3}$$
Similarly, if $\tilde b$ is an approximation to $b$ and has three significant figures, we conclude
$$b = \tilde b ( 1 + \epsilon )$$
where
$$| \epsilon| < 10^{-2}$$
Then what can we say about $ab$? It's clear that
$$ab= \tilde a \tilde b (1+\delta)(1+\epsilon)= \tilde a \tilde b (1+\gamma)$$
where
$$\gamma=\delta+\epsilon+\delta \epsilon$$
Noting that $\epsilon$ is the dominating term in last expression, approximately we have
$$ |\gamma|<10^{-2} $$
Thus we conclude that our result, $\tilde a \tilde b$, has three significant figures, i.e., as many significant figures as the least accurate number given.

The rule of addition can be analyzed in an analogous way. Do this! It's a good practice.

Comment: Why is tilde a being multiplied by delta? I thought it should be a = tilde a + e, where |e|≤0.5×10^-2.

Comment: Other than that I understood what you're saying and it makes sense

Comment: @HritRoy Note that $|\tilde a|>10$ and $a = \tilde a (1 + e/ \tilde a)$

Comment: Could you explain how we can conclude that the product has (is correct to) three significant figures from |γ|<10⁻²?

Comment: @HritRoy Referring to your first comment, that's how we define significant figures (I've neglected the 0.5 for simplicity).

Comment: I meant.. from the fact that tilde $a$ is correct to 4 significant figures we can say |δ|<10^-3. But from |δ|<10^-3, can we say that tilde $a$ is correct to 4 significant figures? That is to say, is the converse also true?

Comment: @HritRoy Yes, that's how we define significant figures.