# Multiplication accuracy after setting precision

Tags: calculus

I have a hard time figuring out if there is a way to know how much accuracy I can expect from a multiplication Result, if I set precision.
For example:

```
A = 1.2345 And (after cutting digits to have 3) a = 1.23
B = 2.3456 And b = 2.34
C = A * B and c = a * b
```

Can I say, for sure I will get 3 digits accuracy from c? Meaning if first 3 digits of c is like C?
Or I can only hope that c and C are almost similar?

I hope I described the problem, it is not a easy one to describe and I’m not a mathematician (I even had a hard time to chose a tag)

Thanks.

Comment: What is relevant here is the number of *significant figures*, which might or might not be the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.  Typically, we take the number of significant figures of the result of multiplication to be the lesser of the number of significant figures of the multiplicands.  In your example, $a$ and $b$ are both rounded to three significant figures and so their product will indeed be accurate to three significant figures as well (*again, emphasizing significant figures, not decimal places*)

Comment: Is there a proof for this? Like how the rounded out values do not effect the the higher digits? For example if there is 5 digits and it is rounded to 3, and after multiplication, you are saying 3 digits will be accurate, but how?

Comment: Let me use an example. If A and B are 1.000999 and a and b are 1.000 (keeping 4 digits) C will be 1.001999 and c will be 1. So ok this case only first 3 digits of C (1.00) are the same as c. And in this example keeping 4 digits in numbers led to 3 digit accuracy in the result. And I want to know how can I prove that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accuracy in multiplication; precision in addition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503449/accuracy-in-multiplication-precision-in-addition)

Comment: It was the closest answer I found before asking this question. But no, I still can not understand how we are sure that how many digits are accurate. As I imagine the removed part may add a tiny amount and creates an overflow leading to change of higher significance digits.